# Validação de campos com Javascript em JSP

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, jsp

```js
function validar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome_passageiro").value;
  var data = document.getElementById("dt_nascimento").value;
  var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
  var modelo = document.getElementById("modelo").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status").find("option[value='"+val+"']");


if (nome == "") {
  alert('Preencha o campo com seu nome');
}else if(data==""){
  alert('Preencha a data');
}else if(cpf==""){
  alert('Preencha o cpf');
}else if(modelo==""){
  alert('Preencha o modelo');
}else if(status==""){
  alert('Preencha o Status');
}else{
  return false;
}

}
```

```html
<h1>Cadastro de Motoristas</h1>
Nome do Motorista:
<input type="text" id="nome_passageiro" /><br/><br/>

Data de Nascimento:
<input type="text" id="dt_nascimento" /><br/><br/>

CPF:
<input type="text" id="cpf" onkeypress="" /><br/><br/>

Modelo de Carro:
<input type="text" id="modelo" /><br/><br/>

Status:
<input list="status" /><br/><br/>

<datalist id="status">
  <option value="-------">
  <option value="Ativo">
  <option value="Inativo">
</datalist>

<button type="button" onkeypress="validar()">Cadastrar</button>
```

Estou fazendo uma validação de campos utilizando o Javascript em uma aplicação jsp mas ela não está funcionando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa mudar de  `onkeypress="validar()"` para  `onclick="validar()"` pois a função deve iniciar assim que o usuário clicar no botão.

Mas vale lembrar que você pode explorar muitos pontos de melhoria no seu código:
Remover os `<br />` desnecessários, utilize `<p>` para parágrafos ou  `<div>` se quiser somente agrupar os campos.

Pensando em melhorar a experiência do usuário ao acessar sua página deixe a validação com IF ao invés de ElseIf. 
É muito melhor para o usuário ver tudo que ele errou de uma vez do que aos poucos, também é valido deixar alguma indicação na página do que é obrigatório.

Na parte em que `<datalist>` não entendi muito o bem o que você queria fazer então deixei comentado para evitar o erro no Javascript.

```js
function validar() {
  var msgErro = "";
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome_passageiro").value;
  var data = document.getElementById("dt_nascimento").value;
  var cpf = document.getElementById("cpf").value;
  var modelo = document.getElementById("modelo").value;
  var status =  document.getElementById("status").value;

if (nome == "") {
  msgErro = msgErro + 'Preencha o campo com seu nome. \n';
}

if(data==""){
  msgErro = msgErro + 'Preencha a data. \n';
}

if(cpf==""){
  msgErro = msgErro + 'Preencha o cpf. \n';
}

if(modelo==""){
  msgErro = msgErro + 'Preencha o modelo. \n';
}

if(status==""){
  msgErro = msgErro + 'Preencha o Status. \n';
}

if(msgErro != ""){
  alert(msgErro);
  return false;
}


}
```

```html
<h1>Cadastro de Motoristas</h1>
<div>
  <label for="nome_passageiro">Nome do Motorista:</label>
  <input type="text" name="nome_passageiro" id="nome_passageiro" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="dt_nascimento">Data de Nascimento:</label>
  <input type="text" name="dt_nascimento" id="dt_nascimento" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" onkeypress="" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="modelo">Modelo de Carro:</label>
  <input type="text" name="modelo" id="modelo" />
</div>

<div>
  <label for="status">Status:</label>
  <select name="status" id="status">
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    <option value="Ativo">Ativo</option>
    <option value="Inativo">Inativo</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  
</div>

<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="validar()">Cadastrar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: cara mudei para onclick e não funcionou

Comment: Estranho, ao executar o código aqui funcionou. Que erro aparece?

Comment: ahh apareceu outro erro rs, na condição do status, no caso status é um data list com duas opçoes ativo e inativo, ele ocorre o erro na seguinte linha. var status = document.getElementById("status").find("option[value='"+val+"']");                     Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined

Comment: Isso porque sua variável **val** não foi definida.

Comment: isso no caso estou querendo pegar o que o usuario vai selecionar no data list

Comment: ele funcionou cara arrumei o val e funcionou vlw

Comment: Você não poderia usar select ao invés desse datalist?